# Where is the Apache configuration located on Linux Mint?

Tags: linux-mint, apache-http-server

Using the command

```
gedit /etc/apache2/httpd.conf
```

produces a text file containing just one line. I need to change the DocumentRoot of my Apache configuration so as to use with the CakePHP framework.

Comment: Seeing you already posted two questions about almost the same topic, I suggest you [do some reading/searching](https://www.google.com/search?q=linux+apache+tutorial&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:es-ES:official&client=firefox-a) **before** asking.

Answer (score 6):

On Debian-based systems (which Mint is), the Apache configuration takes a different approach. Every "site" has its own configuration in `/etc/apache2/sites-available`.
The default configuration is named `default`. So, try:

```
gedit /etc/apache2/sites-available/default
```

Don't forget to reload or restart Apache afterwards:

```
sudo invoke-rc.d apache2 restart
```

As a sidenote, you can create additional configuration files in `/etc/apache2/sites-available` and activate them using:

```
sudo a2ensite <yourconfig>
```

You can disable the same configuration with:

```
sudo a2dissite <yourconfig>
```

Comment: Sorry, I am newb and what you explain really confuses me, I am new to php and webserver setups as well all Linux commands. What is 'site-available' ? Could you help me configure use of cakephp with apache on Mint via http://localhost:80. I use this only to test some things I learn.

Comment: `sites-available` is just another folder on the hard drive. Instead of opening `httpd.conf` in gedit, you have to open another file in a nested folder (that file is named `default`). I wish I could provide you with some screenshots, but I'm having some trouble with that.

Comment: Attention, the file may be with name 000-default.conf, same goes for the SSL file, wich is default-ssl.conf.