# Apache configuration in Mint 14 not working

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, linux-mint, lamp

I usually install mysql, apache and php using the following commands

```
sudo apt-get install apache2 php5 libapache2-mod-php5 php5-mysql
```

but after I did a fresh upgrade to Linux mint 14, I got these two errors

```
* Starting web server apache2                                                  
apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1 for ServerName
[Sun Mar 10 01:44:38 2013] [warn] NameVirtualHost *:8080 has no VirtualHosts
                                                                         [ OK ]
Setting up libapache2-mod-php5 (5.4.6-1ubuntu1.1) ...
 * Reloading web server config                                                  
 apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1 for ServerName
[Sun Mar 10 01:44:39 2013] [warn] NameVirtualHost *:8080 has no VirtualHosts
                                                                         [ OK ]
```

I get the same error when i restart apache server as well. I haven't been able to make changes the directory of the localhost because of this.

Comment: Those are only warnings and should not impact the performance of Apache. You won't see anything on the `:8080` virtual host, but the default `:80` should still be fine. What's your problem with the "directory of the localhost"?

Comment: whenever i type http://localhost/ I get an error saying that the location does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

To fix that problem, you need edit your **apache2.conf** file (`/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`), and set `ServerName`.

Simply add the following line to the file:

```
ServerName localhost
```

Save the file and exit the editor. Don't forget to restart apache.

Comment: I looked for the httpd.conf file in my apache2 directory and there was no httpd.conf file there. It's strange, can I paste some other httpd.conf from somewhere else to make it work ? 

Here are the contents of the directory 

apache2.conf  envvars  mods-available  ports.conf       sites-enabled
conf.d        magic    mods-enabled    sites-available

Comment: @Bazinga777: OK, sorry, I didn't check which Linux you were running. Try this [post](http://superuser.com/questions/387966/where-is-the-apache-configuration-located-on-linux-mint) for the possible location of the httpd.conf file.

Comment: I tried it and i configured the localhost. Didn't work.I'm trying something else out right now. Will update the post if it works.